# Can we create nullable/nonnull property in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Can we create nullable/nonnull property in objective-c if yes then how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is nonnull in objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002033/what-is-nonnull-in-objective-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the null-related property attributes in XCode do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532640/what-do-the-null-related-property-attributes-in-xcode-do)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `_Nullable` and `_Nonnull` qualifiers

```
@property (copy, nullable) NSString *name;
@property (copy, nonnull) NSArray *allItems;
```

nonnull: Indicates that the pointer should/will never be nil. Pointers annotated with nonnull are imported into Swift as their non-optional base value (i.e., NSData).

nullable: Indicates that the pointer can be nil in general practice. Imported into Swift as an optional value (NSURL?).

Comment: I think i don't have this "nullable/nonnull" headers installed, i get errors, why headers do i need to update ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `_Nullable` and `_Nonnull` qualifiers as you see fit. (Put them in the same place as you'd place a `const` qualifier).

Comment: Can you please give one example so that can help us?