# How to stop objc code from transforming into optional

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, payment-gateway, payment-processing

so i'm using this payment gateway called "moip"(im from brazil, stripe doesn't work in here) that takes user's credit card info and makes a hash (because of sensitive data transfer etc). But for some reason this code needs a 2 length type string for month and year and when i pass these values they become optional, so the main function(that makes the hash) doesn't work and returns nil. Example code:

```
func createHash() -> String? {            
    let creditCard = MPKCreditCard()
    creditCard.number = "1234567891234567"
    creditCard.expirationMonth = "01"
    creditCard.expirationYear = "19"
    creditCard.cvc = "123"
    return MoipSDK.encryptCreditCard(creditCard)
}
```

This is the object MPKCreditCard in objc:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MPKCardType.h"

@interface MPKCreditCard : NSObject

@property NSString *number;
@property NSString *cvc;
@property NSString *expirationMonth;
@property NSString *expirationYear;

- (BOOL) isNumberValid;
- (BOOL) isSecurityCodeValid;
- (BOOL) isExpiryDateValid;
- (MPKCardType) cardType;

@end
```

Property "isEspiryDateValid" of course always returns false, the other ones are ok.

```
- (BOOL) isExpiryDateValid {
    return [self isValidLengthExpiryDate] && [self isValidDate];
}

- (BOOL)isValidLengthExpiryDate {
    return self.expirationMonth.length == 2 && (self.expirationYear.length == 2 || self.expirationYear.length == 4);
}

- (BOOL)isValidDate {
    if (self.expirationMonth <= 0 || [self month] > 12) return NO;

    return [self isValidWithDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

And this is the function that creates the hash:

```
+ (NSString *)encryptCreditCard:(MPKCreditCard*)creditCard {

    NSString *valueToEncrypt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number=%@&cvc=%@&expirationMonth=%@&expirationYear=%@", creditCard.number, creditCard.cvc, creditCard.expirationMonth, creditCard.expirationYear];
    NSLog(@"%@", valueToEncrypt);
    NSString *encriptedData = [MPKUtilities encryptData:valueToEncrypt keyTag:kPublicKeyName];

    if (encriptedData) {
        return encriptedData;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I don't get much about objc but the property doesn't look different from the others(that would turn the value into an optional).

I know the payment gateway company should provide me the solution, and i believe they will, but today(sept 07) is independence day and nothing works. So i could reeaaally use your help otherwise just monday :(

For short, my problem is: i pass unwrapped non-optional values to expirationMonth and expirationYear. But when the object(mpkcreditcard) receives them, it turns them into optionals.

Thank you so much, guys!

Comment: `self.expirationMonth` is an `NSString` but you compare it against the integer `0`. That's bad.

Comment: Your issue is unclear. You posted a lot of code but it's not clear what your actual problem is. Please clarify.

Comment: @rmaddy i changed `self.expirationMonth` to `month` which is the integer value and it still doesn't work. My problem is: i pass unwrapped non-optional values to expirationMonth and expirationYear. But when the object(mpkcreditcard) receives them, it turns them into optionals.

Comment: That's the confusing part. What do you mean by *"But when the object(mpkcreditcard) receives them, it turns them into optionals"*?

Comment: Believe me, its confusing for me too hahaha. I don't why that's happening, i pass to `creditcard.expirationYear` a value like `"22"` and when i print `credit card.expirationYear` i get `Optional["22"]`

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure what the issue is but given that you mentioned Objective-C and optionals I'm going to recommend you take a look at https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-nullable-to-annotate-objective-c/ it talks about how to mark things in Objective-C to indicate optionality to Swift. It might be of help

Comment: @brenosilva You need to post exact code that fully demonstrates the issue you are seeing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232944/can-we-create-nullable-nonnull-property-in-objective-c

Comment: breno silva, just for your information: in Objective-C, all properties are optional by default. They contain either nil (0) or some value.

Comment: Optional does not seem to be the cause of your issue. What is the output of `NSLog(@"%@", valueToEncrypt);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the question as it stands but I believe what you are running into is that all those values in obj-c are nullable, so when bridged back to swift, they become optionals. You will just have to unwrap them to use them...

```
guard let experationMonth = creditcard.experationYear else { /* handle null */ }
print("\(experationMonth)")
```

This should print an unwrapped string without the optional[""]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mark properties as *nonnull* when you want to pass them to Swift.

```
@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSString *number;
@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSString *cvc;
@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSString *expirationMonth;
@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSString *expirationYear;
```

Marking types as *nonnull* imports them as non-optional in Swift.